# Angular: Can't get synchronization except after the second click on mat-select radio

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I'm following [my previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56752008/get-the-default-value-of-select-radio-angular-6).

My problem:

is that there isn't synchronization between the ***profession libelle that I selected*** and the **displayed profession libelle**.

The cause is:

`localStorage` inside the method `radioChecked(id, i, pro)` doesn't works for the ***first time***. It gives the **CORRECT** result after the ***second click***.

Have you please any idea about solving this bug ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for your help. But I'd like to tell you that I get `this.selectedProfessionRadio` as `undefined` while it's inside subscribe. So, to resolve my problem, I try add `this.selectedProfessionRadio = pro.libelle` outside subscribe . ==> And so, I can get the correct result without the use of `localStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

**the why?**
If you go to chrome developer tools... in the Application Tab you'll see 2 different keys

- ProfessionLibelle
- ProfessionLibe

Upon investigating the code, when the page initializes (*ngOnInit*)

1. you're reading from a service
2. removing the existing Item from local storage
3. setting the local storage with the value returned from the service
4. This means that by-default, the value will always be the value that the service returns... not the value in the local storage

Once you click the radio buttons (method: *radioChecked*), relevant value will be set in the local storage and displayed on screen.

To get **the fix for your particular question**: i removed reading the value from the service and we are now reading from the localStorage in **ngOnInit**

relevant **TS**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, NgForm, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Profession } from './profession.model';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  selectedProfessionRadio = '';
  professionLib: string;
  editForm: FormGroup;
  usrId: String;

  professions: Profession[] =
    [
      { id: 1, libelle: "Engineer", selected: false },
      { id: 2, libelle: "Student", selected: false },
    ];

  radioChecked(id, i, pro) {
    this.professions.forEach(pro => {
      if (pro.id !== id) {
        pro.selected = false;
      }
      else {
        pro.selected = true;
      }
    })

    this.userService.getProfessionById(id).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      pro = data as Profession;

      localStorage.removeItem("ProfessionLibelle");
      localStorage.setItem("ProfessionLibelle", pro.libelle);
      this.selectedProfessionRadio = localStorage.getItem("ProfessionLibelle");
    }, error => console.log(error));

  }

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let userId = localStorage.getItem("editUserId");
    this.usrId = localStorage.getItem("editUserId");

    this.selectedProfessionRadio = localStorage.getItem("ProfessionLibelle");
    this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group
      ({
        id: [],
        name: ['', Validators.required],
        pro: [this.selectedProfessionRadio, Validators.required]
      });

    this.userService.getUserId(+userId).subscribe(data => {
      this.editForm.patchValue(data);
    });
  }

  onSubmit() { }
}
```

complete [working stackblitz available here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jm8rmz-zh4bzb)

Comment: Hello Sir, Thanks a lot for your help. But I'd like to tell you that I get `this.selectedProfessionRadio` as `undefined` while it's inside subscribe and subscribe cannot maintain synchronization. So, to resolve my problem, I try add `this.selectedProfessionRadio = pro.libelle` outside subscribe . ==> And so, I can get the correct result without the use of `localStorage`